# How to set subview as a first responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to close the image View while clicking on close button.but button does not responds to touch event.
here is my code:

```
-(void)imageTouchUP:(id)sender
{
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 30 , 30)];
    imageView.image=self.testimonialImage;
    imageView.tag=1;
    UIButton *closeButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    closeButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    [closeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:closeButton];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIView *subView=[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the UIImageView to handle touches you need to set userInteractionEnabled to YES, it defaults to NO. 
Try:

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/userInteractionEnabled)

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 property of UIImageView `userInteractionEnabled` and its value is by default NO. So in your code add

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 30 , 30)];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's another view with tag=1 in your self.view. Please try to edit button clicked like this:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)btn
{
    UIView *view = btn.superview;
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```